# How to divide two EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to divide two `EditTexts`?

```
ed number one = 80 

ed number two = 3.0625
```

But when I click button to divide them, the app has a force close. How to solve this problem?

My xml:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:numeric="80" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:numeric="3.0625" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

and here is the code

```
public class main  extends Activity {
EditText one,two,result;
Button calc;
BigDecimal onex,twox;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);// = 80
    two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.two);// = 3.0625
    result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);// result
calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onex = new BigDecimal(one.getText().toString());
        twox = new BigDecimal(two.getText().toString());
        result.setText((onex).divide(twox).toString());     
    }
});

}
```

**How to make the dividing work correctly without any force close?**

Comment: post logcat stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You have to get text values of edittexts and convert them to BigDecimal in your case. try below code:

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BigDecimal bigOne, bigTwo, bigResult;

        try {
            bigOne = new BigDecimal(one.getText().toString());
            bigTwo = new BigDecimal(two.getText().toString());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fill texts with some numeric values" + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        bigResult = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        try {
            bigResult = bigOne.divide(bigTwo);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Check your numeric values" + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        result.setText(String.valueOf(bigResult));

    }
});
```

**Edit:** Also `android:numeric` can only have `integer`, `signed` and `decimal`. You are using it wrongly.

```
android:numeric="3.0625"
```

Should be;
`android:numeric="integer"` or `android:numeric="signed"` or `android:numeric="decimal"`

To set value to editTexts use:
`android:text="80"` and `android:text="3.0625"`

Comment: Why do you propose the use of BigDecimal instead of double? Also, you may not need to try..catch the block if you set `android:inputType="number"` in your TextView.

Comment: I used BigDecimal because question involves BigDecimals. And we need try/catch block if user did not enter anything to editTexts.

Comment: i tried this code and modified edit text as text=80 but still give error . if there is any tutorial for how the dividing work in android or calc tutorials please send to me link about it

Comment: You don't have any problem with division. Code I've posted should not cause any errors. You may see a Toast. what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

When value does not include decimal point (80) BigDecimal will treat it as Zero.

Insert `80.0`.